# Idiom for transducing over an atom?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, transducer

What is the idiomatic way to apply transducers to an atom's value?

This seems to do the job, but I'm unsure of correctness (and style ^^).

```
 (let [xf1 (map inc) 
       xf2 (map #(+ % 2)) 
       xf #(vec (eduction (comp xf2 xf1) %)) 
       a (atom [1 2 3])] 
   (swap! a xf))
 ;=> [4 5 6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(let [xf1 (map inc) 
      xf2 (map #(* % 2)) 
      foo #(into [] (comp xf2 xf1) %) 
      a (atom [1 2 3])] 
  (swap! a foo))
;; => [3 5 7]
```

There are two things you need to take note.

1. `comp` in transducers works the opposite order as normal applications. That is, `xf2` is applied prior to `xf1`. For each element, it is doubled then incremented.
2. `eduction` returns a sequence, so it's not the same type as your original value in the atom.

Comment: Why then make `foo` a function for `swap!` and not just a value for `(reset! a foo)`? Regarding 2. I was lazy, editing to get a vector. Regarding 1. I was aware of this, hence the "reverse" order in comp. Editing for idiomatic `(map inc)`, thx.

Comment: Good question. In this case, a `swap!` is indeed no different from a `reset!` with values given, because the atom is created locally and never used outside. However, atoms are meant to be used in multiple threads, thus, it would be more idiomatic to put the read-then-writeback logic in a STM. Thus, two calls from different threads will always end up transforming the atom twice. If the read is outside transaction, it is possible that the result is only transformed once.